# Como hago para que mis datos de un método pasen a otra clase

Tags: java, netbeans, metodos

Tengo este código para generar números aleatorios en un método y cuando lo llamo en otra clase no me trae nada, pienso que me falta algo pero no estoy seguro de si es que no meti algo o me estoy saltando un paso para los datos

```
    int num = 0, valor = 0, pazar;

        Random numeros = new Random();      //Creo un random para la probabilidad de 2 o 4
        num = numeros.nextInt(1, 5);

        if (num == 1 || num == 2 || num == 3) {
            valor = 2;
        } else if (num == 4) {
            valor = 4;
        }

        pazar = numeros.nextInt(1, 17);     //Creo otro random para el lugar al azar

        if (pazar == 1 && v1 == 0) {
            v1 = valor;
        } else if (pazar == 2 && v2 == 0) {
            v2 = valor;
        } else if (pazar == 3 && v3 == 0) {
            v3 = valor;
        } else if (pazar == 4 && v4 == 0) {
            v4 = valor;
        } else if (pazar == 5 && v5 == 0) {
            v5 = valor;
        } else if (pazar == 6 && v6 == 0) {
            v6 = valor;
        } else if (pazar == 7 && v7 == 0) {
            v7 = valor;
        } else if (pazar == 8 && v8 == 0) {
            v8 = valor;
        } else if (pazar == 9 && v9 == 0) {
            v9 = valor;
        } else if (pazar == 10 && v10 == 0) {
            v10 = valor;
        } else if (pazar == 11 && v11 == 0) {
            v11 = valor;
        } else if (pazar == 12 && v12 == 0) {
            v12 = valor;
        } else if (pazar == 13 && v13 == 0) {
            v13 = valor;
        } else if (pazar == 14 && v14 == 0) {
            v14 = valor;
        } else if (pazar == 15 && v15 == 0) {
            v15 = valor;
        } else if (pazar == 16 && v16 == 0) {
            v16 = valor;
        }
```

yo lo ocupo en esta parte por que tengo un frame donde me va a mostrar los datos al usuario

```
        Metodos m = new Metodos();

        m.GenerarRandom(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10, v11, v12, v13, v14, v15, v16);
```

Comment: Hola Alessandro, qué resultado esperas que te devuelva?
A tu método le falta un  `return <algo>`

Comment: Gracias de verdad, no sabia lo de los return hasta que me los encontre de pura casualidad y ya pude, de verdad gracias!!